# When using popToRootViewController I lose my navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I have an iOS app where the main screen is a UICollectionViewController.  When selecting an Item from the collection view the view is pushed to a detail view of the item.  In the detail view I built a drawer/slider that moves out from the side.  In order to get the view to look the way I wanted I hid the default navigation bar and inserted one via storyboards.

[image: ScreenShot]

I ran into an issue that when hiding the default navigation bar you lose the back button functionality that comes with using a navigation controller.  I worked around this by adding a button where the back button would have been (the image above is shown without the button). Now I use the line of code below to move back to the collection view.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It works the way I want it except that I lose my Navigation Bar when I return to the collection view.  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In viewWillAppear of your rootViewControler

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Wow! Hands down the easiest fix I've had to make.  That was fast enough to implement that I cannot except your answer for another couple minutes!  Thanks a ton UFO checkmark goes to you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread it's a little dated (more than dated more like an archive). But I ran into the same issue in swift 5, Xcode 13. Below is the swift code that I used in my viewWillAppear in case it helps someone.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false , animated: true)
```