# Navigation bar hides when using popToRootViewControllerAnimated in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my App, I have to redirect users to my rootview from my login screen.

I used `popViewControllerAnimated` it just pops only one view.

So i am using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`. But when i am doing it the Navigation bar hides. 
I referred some links  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456189/when-using-poptorootviewcontroller-i-lose-my-navigation-bar) & implemented it. But it is of no use.

**Tried Code**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Thanks in advance!